# Hide CAB on EditText long press showing the Selection Markers

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-edittext

First of all, I have **searched and tried numerous solutions posted here** in StackOverflow but none of them solves my query, so this **isn't a duplicate question**.

I want to display a custom menu like this, when an `EditText` is long pressed,

[image: Popup menu with selection markers active]

As you can see that on Long Press on the `EditText`, this floating menu appears **instead of the stock CAB**, and the selection markers are also intact.

I want to achieve this kind of menu for my app. I have tried using this code, while it disabled the CAB but also prevents the selection markers from appearing,

```
editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
```

Also, if I try customizing the CAB menu, it **won't render a menu like this**, it will just alter the buttons on the existing CAB.

How can I achieve this floating menu along with the selection markers visible, when the `EditText` is long pressed or double tapped?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use EditText's getSelectionStart and getSelectionEnd when the OS ActionMode starts (by overriding Activity's onActionModeStarted), then close the OS ActionMode and start your own while manually highlighting the appropriate text using EditText's setSelection.

Comment: Tried setting the selection by using `editText.setSelection(start,stop)` inside `onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode)` and also closed the mode by using `mode.finish()`.

Doesn't work, nothing happened. The same CAB appeared.

Comment: You want to setSelection AFTER closing the mode. I.e. you allow the OS ActionMode to start as normal, you determine the selection start and end, THEN close the ActionMode, FINALLY setSelection using the start and end. If setSelection is causing the OS ActionMode to start again, then setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback with an intermediary version which returns true in onCreateActionMode, setting your original one back after your custom text-selection handling is finished.